# Convert decimal to currency in C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010

Hi guys i have a label on my website which shows the price of items on the pages. The t shirt page currently displays price for a t-shirt as 55 and i want it to show  as £55 . I would like the label to show price in £ currency format. My current code is below. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks for your time...

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("#,##0.00") %>'>
```

Comment: Wouldnt <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("c") %>'> work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your format string to use `c`, this will format your string as a currency value.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("c") %>'>
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to format it to currency for the specified culture. The example below should work:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Price")).ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")) %>'>
```